# Whats wrong with this SQL update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I added a "FirstDesignTitle" column to my Orders table and am trying to update its initial value (and then keep it up to date through business logic).  My tables are:

```
Orders
------
OrderID
FirstDesignTitle


LineItem
--------
LineItemID
OrderID
DesignID


Design
------
DesignID
DesignTitle
```

"First" means the lowest-LineItemID'd LineItem that has a DesignID (the column is nullable).  The update statement I've got is:

```
UPDATE Orders
SET FirstDesignTitle = t.DesignTitle
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (1) [t4].[value] as DesignTitle
    FROM (
        SELECT (
            SELECT [t3].[DesignTitle]
            FROM (
                SELECT TOP (1) [t1].[DesignID]
                FROM [dbo].[LineItem] AS [t1]
                WHERE ([t1].[DesignID] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t1].[OrderID] = [t0].[OrderID])
                ORDER BY [t1].[LineItemID] ASC
                ) AS [t2]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Design] AS [t3] ON [t3].[DesignID] = [t2].[DesignID]
        ) AS [value], [t0].[OrderID]
        FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [t0]
    ) AS [t4]
    WHERE [t4].[OrderID] = orderid
    ORDER BY DesignTitle DESC
) t
```

However, I only get a single DesignTitle to populate all Orders, rather than what I want, which is for each order to show its first LineItem's DesignTitle.  The DesignTitle that populates is the lastmost DesignTitle in the Designs table, starting with the letters "ZZZ".  Can anyone describe/fix what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your syntax looks like SQL Server, so I'm tagging the question appropriately.

Comment: Using `top` without an `order by` is dangerous.  Ordering is not guarateed unless you specify an `order by`, and the server can return whatever single row is easiest for it to return.

Comment: All of the `top 1`s with no `order by` may be causing any NULLs you have in the table to be sorted to the first row and selected.  Try running your subqueries one at a time starting from the innermost one to see what is returned.

Comment: I edited my post to show an updated query that incorporates an `order by`  for each `top`, and now I see all my FirstDesignTitle columns showing the Last Design in the Design table, with first letters "ZZZ".

Comment: When you say "lowest-ID", you are talking about LineItemId? It isn't there in your shcema

Comment: @AXMIM Yes, sorry about that.  I modified the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way to achieve what you want using CTE

```
;WITH CTELineItem
AS
(
    SELECT Sequence = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OrderID ORDER BY LineItemID ASC),
            OrderID,
            DesignID
    FROM LineItem
    WHERE DesignID IS NOT NULL
)

UPDATE Orders
SET Orders.FirstDesignTitle = Design.DesignTitle
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN CTELineItem AS FirstLineItem ON FirstLineItem.Sequence = 1 
                                        AND Orders.OrderID = FirstLineItem.OrderID
INNER JOIN Design ON FirstLineItem.DesignID = Design.DesignID
```

Comment: I get an error: Incorrect syntax near 'ROW_NUMBER', expected 'OVER'

Comment: The update fixed that error, however, I get a "1 row(s) affected", instead of the 700000+ I'd been shooting for, and I can't find the one row that was affected.

Comment: oup, fixed by adding partition

Comment: Also added handling null design in the LineItem, should work fine now

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thank you very much!  I'll read about why the `partition by` made the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why your query is not working.  An alternative approach uses a correlated subquery:

```
update orders
    set firstdesigntitle = (select top 1 d.designtitle
                            from lineitem li join
                                 design d
                                 on li.designid = d.designid
                            where li.orderid = orders.orderid
                            order by d.designid asc
                           );
```

You don't specify how "first" is defined.  This uses the smallest `designid`.

Comment: Can't use ORDER BY without a Top selector and also can't alias the Orders table in an update statement.  Nevertheless, thanks!

Comment: Good solution, only missing TOP 1 in select d.designtitle

Comment: It doesn't work, actually.  After adding the top(1) for d.designtitle, I get all Orders' FirstDesignTitle column being the same design, the first in the Designs table, alphabetically ordered.

Comment: @jeromeyers . . . You should only get the first design for the order.  The `where` clause does mean something in a correlated subquery.